# I need help identifying where a working Google Apps Script exists. Is there a way to reverse lookup where the deployment exists if I have the ID?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, drive

Ok. So long story short, I'm trying to find the location of a WORKING app that was created for my company in the past. The employee that created it no longer works here and I need to find where the script exists in order to change some code. The app is functioning and we use it on a regular basis. We have the former employee's Google Drive contents but it doesn't appear that the app is in that directory. Is there any way to reverse lookup the location if we have the app's URL or ID?

Comment: First, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `if we have the app's URL or ID`, if you have already known the URL of the Google Apps Script project, can you open the Google Apps Script project by the script editor? If my understanding is correct, what does `I'm trying to find the location of a WORKING app` mean? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.